# Angular Material MatSnackBar doesn't show with text

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a problem with displaying MatSnackBar when I use this kind of code:

```
this.matSnackBar.open(err.error.message, "X", {duration:1000, verticalPosition:'bottom', horizontalPosition:'center'})
```

and this code displays mat snackbar like this:

[image]

but when I click wherever on the page mat snack bar displays properly.
How to display mat snack bar properly without clicking on-page?

Comment: What code do you exactly need? I run this matSnackBar from interceptor

Comment: What does the console say? Hardcode a string in there first. If it shows up something is wrong with the way you're passing a message down.

Comment: console says nothing, I also hardcoded value and nothing  has changed

Comment: I have 4 module and in one of them I registered interceptor where I run MatStackBar and I registered SnackBarModule in module where I registered interceptor

Comment: It could be a problem with how the view updates. After the click actions its displaying correct so I guess nothing to do with importing it correctly. U use maybe ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush on the component anywhere? inject the ChangedetectorRef and try calling cd.detectChanges().

Comment: @sagat thank you very much,  your answer with ChangedetectorRef fixed the problem

Comment: @MateuszSobczak no problem mate. Always if the view does not update properly, take into consideration that the changes are not properly propagated to the angular changedetection or check if u because of the change of the strategy have to propagate it manually. Cheers

Comment: @sagat today, I learned it too! Thanks for right direction.

Comment: cheers! Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Since it is displayed properly after you click on the page, it means you have an issue with the angular change detection strategy. You can perhaps propagate it manually.

Import ChangeDetectorRef:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Inject ChangeDetectorRef:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Call the markForCheck method after displaying the snackbar

```
this.matSnackBar.open(err.error.message, "X", {duration:1000, verticalPosition:'bottom', horizontalPosition:'center'})
this.cdr.markForCheck();
```

Entire code:

```js
import { ..., ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ... {

  constructor(..., private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  myFunction() {
    ...
    this.matSnackBar.open(err.error.message, "X", {duration:1000, verticalPosition:'bottom', horizontalPosition:'center'})
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }
}
```